# Квадратное уравнение всегда выдает 0.0е+000. Почему?

Tags: pascal

```
program quadratic;

function quadratic(a, b, c: real; var x1, x2: real): Boolean;
var
        d, s: real;
begin
        begin
        if a = 0 then
                quadratic := false;
                exit
        end;
        d := b*b - 4*a*c;
        begin
        if d < 0 then
                quadratic := false;
                exit
        end;
        s := sqrt(d);
        x1 := (-b - s) / (2*a);
        x2 := (-b + s) / (2*a);
        quadratic := true
end;

var
        g, h: real;

begin
        writeln(quadratic(2, 3, -5, g, h));
        writeln(g, h);
end.
```

Доброго времени суток. Вроде бы всё просто, я хочу вывести на экран результаты квадратного уравнения с заданными значениями, вывожу переменные с помощью writeln, но результат всегда один:

```
TRUE
0.0000000000000000E+000 0.0000000000000000E+000
```

Погуглил, ответа не нашел, может быть не понимаю как вопрос задать в поисковую строку.

Comment: `begin if d < 0 then` опечатка?

Comment: Плохо помню паскаль, но скорее всего вы передаете аргументы по значению, поэтому g и h в итоге не изменяются

Comment: Зачем вообще передавать g и h - используйте их внутри функции тоже

Comment: Я создал переменные после функции, и по порядку (четвертой и пятой) вставил в параметры функции, выводя её результат (boolean) на экран, выдает true, условия соблюдены. Далее я вывожу на экран переменные, которые присвоили себе значения в параметрах функции. Должны выводиться результаты параметров переменных x1(которая передала результат в g) и x2(которая передала результат в h), что я и сделал с помощью writeln(g, h). Опечатки нет, не понимаю что за аргументы по значению вообще и как использовать g и h внутри функции и зачем.

Comment: 1) `begin if a = 0 then` -> `if a = 0 then begin` 2) `begin if d < 0 then` -> `if d < 0 then begin`.

Comment: Блин, я понял, извиняюсь за тупость :D

Comment: Путать поведение функций и процедур - порочная практика. Передаёте в качестве аргументов переменные, которые будут изменены в процессе работы - перед вами процедура. Функция должна в конце иметь return result; и бережно обращаться с аргументами ей переданными.

Comment: @Quazimorda ???

Comment: @nx4n В паскале есть два механизма: процедуры и функции. И работают эти механизмы по-разному. Функция должна возвращать значение того или иного типа, но не меняет значения в аргументах, переданных её на вход. Процедура наоборот, ничего не возвращает, но часто меняет значения в аргументах. У вас вроде функция, но и аргументы вы меняете. Это смешивание поведения механизмов. Скажем так, это не чистый код. ))